# Loop SUM based on criteria of 2 cells

Tags: excel, vba

I need a bit of help with Excel VBA.

I have 3 columns with data W, X, Y:

[image: What I have]

Final result is to sum all X and Y with same value and get something like this with changing value in W column:

[image: What needs to happen]

Comment: this will get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36821985/how-to-combine-duplicate-rows-and-sum-the-values-3-column-in-excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work :D

```
Sub Sort01()

   lRow = 2
   Do While (Cells(lRow, 23) <> "")

    ItemRow1 = Cells(lRow, "Y")
    ItemRow2 = Cells(lRow + 1, "Y")

    lengthRow1 = Cells(lRow, "X")
    lengthRow2 = Cells(lRow + 1, "X")

    If ((ItemRow1 = ItemRow2) And (lengthRow1 = lengthRow2)) Then
        Cells(lRow, "W") = Cells(lRow, "W") + Cells(lRow + 1, "W")
        Rows(lRow + 1).Delete

    Else
        lRow = lRow + 1
    End If
Loop
End sub
```

Comment: Hi dzunaa - don't forget to Accept your answer. This will be possible from 48 hours after posting the answer.