# Merge matching rows in excel & summarizing matching columns

Tags: excel, merge

Looking to merge some data and summarize the results. Bene poking around google but haven't found anything that will match up duplicates and summarize.

The left side of the table is what I'm starting with, I would like the output on the right side.

```
Street          Name        Widgets Sprockets   Nuts    Bolts       Street      Name        Widgets Sprockets   Nuts    Bolts
123 Any street  ACB Co          10  248         2       50      123 Any street  ACB Co          10  846     10  78
123 Any street  Bob's plumbing  25  22          2       7       123 Any street  Bob's plumbing  25  22      2   7
456 Another st  Bill's cars     55  5           456             456 Another st  Bill's cars     62  878     13  55
123 Any street  ACB Co          54  4           6       789     789 Ave         Shelley and co  5   2       2   78
456 Another st  Bill's cars     7   878         8       55      789 Ave         Divers down     7   90      10  11
789 Ave         Shelley and co  5   2           2       78      456 Another st  ACB Co          6   50      5   
123 Any street  ACB Co          544 4           22                              
456 Another st  ACB Co          6   50          5                               
789 Ave         Divers down     6   90          9       4                           
789 Ave         Divers down     1   1           7
```

Comment: Use something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36821985/how-to-combine-duplicate-rows-and-sum-the-values-3-column-in-excel

Comment: Some ideas on formatting tables for SE http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables

Comment: From the example data it's not clear what sum's up. Is there some data missing, missaligned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Pivot Tables an set the layout to tabular.
Details can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LkFPBn7sgEc