# Excel/Merging Related

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I have an excel question. I have a call center employees' results data.

[image]

I have same named people in different rows. I want to sum those numbers which have the same name. I can do this with sumif formula. But also i need those names to become singular automatically. Can i do that?

Do you guys know any formula which combines those two things?

Thanks.

Comment: Careful with data related to persons. That said you are looking for this QA https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985701/how-to-consolidate-duplicates-in-excel-where-several-columns-need-to-remain-unco

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to consolidate duplicates in Excel where several columns need to remain uncosolidated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985701/how-to-consolidate-duplicates-in-excel-where-several-columns-need-to-remain-unco)

Answer (score 1):

Use a pivot table. A pivot table allows you to specify an aggregation and a column to aggregate over