# Remove duplicates depending on another column, then add corresponding values of the removed duplicates vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with removing duplicates and adding their corresponding values - dependent on whether or not they are duplicates from another column. In this case, if the part number is duplicate under the same work order, then remove duplicate - however, add all values. I will need avoid removing duplicates from another work order number.

[image]

Comment: You can use a pivot table.

Comment: I need a macro to call. It will be part of a larger code

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36821985/how-to-combine-duplicate-rows-and-sum-the-values-3-column-in-excel

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it will add a column to the right, use formula to SumIF, then paste the results as values and delete column C to bring the data to the correct column, then remove duplicates to give you the summary expected:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    'declare and set worksheet, amend as required
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'get the last row with data from Column A

    Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(C[-2],RC[-2],C[-1])"
    'enter a sumif formula to add all with same item number
    Range("D2:D" & LastRow).FillDown 'fill the formula to the last row
    Range("D2:D" & LastRow).Copy 'copy
    Range("D2:D" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    'paste as values
    Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    'delete column C and bring to the left the values calculated by formula
    Range("$A$1:$D$" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4), Header:=xlYes
    'remove duplicates
End Sub
```